# Configure the Group of generated .app files in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'd like that generated `.app` files reside in the `Products` group (or any other group I choose), instead of in project's root.

For example:

[image: Xcode]

How can I instruct Xcode to put the generated `.app` files inside specific groups?

Comment: You can drag it there and it will stay put.

Comment: Nope. As soon as you clean, close and reopen Xcode, it will be in the project's root again.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I'll leave the comment so people know you've tried that. 